# How can I get the current upload rate of my server in PHP?

Tags: php, linux

I would like to get the current upload- and download rate of my root servers in PHP. 
The command line tool **ifstat** displays the values I would like to use:

[image]

Is there any way I can get these values in PHP too? All of my servers are Debian/Linux servers.

Comment: Sure, just parse `/proc/net/dev`.

Comment: Execute shell command using the shell_exec() function in PHP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, just parse `/proc/net/dev`.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I noticed I can make things even easier and just: cat /sys/class/net/eth0/statistics/tx_bytes (or rx_bytes for the number of received bytes)